# rdesktop gives ERROR: Failed to open display:

Tags: 16.04, remote-desktop, rdesktop

I have a `.bash_aliases` file with several aliases which I use to connect to Windows machines. The aliases are set up like this:

```
rdesktop -d domain -u username -p password -k fr-be -g 1920x1024 -T Customer-SupportPC -a 24 IP
```

Yesterday the connection was working fine, today the connection gives me following error:

```
ERROR: Failed to open display:
```

SSH sessions are no problem, it's only a problem with rdesktop to a Windows server. X11 forwarding is set to yes in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: Have you tried to set display `DISPLAY=:0.0 rdesktop <server>`? Your didn't change something? How was your last time connection? How you terminate your session? Does any `rdesktop` is still running? if yes, you would need to kill those sessions first as it caused the DISPLAY used by that session still and doesn't allocate same display thought

Comment: @αғsнιη I have set DISPLAY to 0 but not for a specific server, makes no difference except it shows display:0 in the error. No, I did not change something. What do you mean by last time connection? I usually terminate my session by closing the rdesktop screen but when I get this error I use ctrl + c. There are no rdesktop procs in ps -ef

Comment: Are you in GNU screen or tmux?  Do you get the same error when you run `xclock`?

Comment: AFAIK you need to `export` the `DISPLAY` variable, not `set` it. Otherwise child processes, like your `rdesktop`, won't inherit it.

Answer (score 0):

I have never had any luck with the rdesktop program.  I have great luck with the remmina package. If you don't mind, I suggest you try that and see if it solves this.